# How can many members work on the same file of coding

Tags: android, android-studio, collaboration

Is there any way to have two people edit the same file under a Android project using Android Studio? Actually I am working with a team member where we need to edit the same file with she working on a certain part of the file while I work on another. I could use git but she is not much confident with git.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Then she needs to learn git.

Comment: Yes surely she needs to but this is not the right time :) Is there something else you would like to suggest? @ZamronyP.Juhara

Comment: "Is there a tool that allows me to do X? I already found a tool that allows me to do X but I don't know how to use it". You need to learn how to use git.

Comment: Well the problem is I know how to use git but she doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Use [BitBucket](http://bitbucket.org) it provides feature for private repositories, what [GitHub](http://github.com) provides with money.

Comment: Thank you for response Sir :). We already have private repo for our project. I just need a collaboration tool which can somehow make her able to see me edit the code on my android studio editor screen in real time.

Comment: Use TeamViewer then.

Comment: Tried it but I only want the team member to see my Android studio screen and nothing else at all.